# Reading comma values

Tags: sas

How to read below data in SAS?

```
Yellowstone           ID/MT/WY 1872 *  4,065,493
Everglades            FL 1934 *        1,398,800
Yosemite              CA 1864 *          760,917
Great Smoky Mountains NC/TN 1926 *       520,269
Wolf Trap Farm        VA 1966 *              130
```

For last column I only get:

```
406549
1
.
520
.
```

Code:

```
data math;
    input 
        parkname $ 1-22
        state $
        year
        asteriks $
        value COMMA9.;
    datalines;
Yellowstone           ID/MT/WY 1872 *  4,065,493
Everglades            FL 1934 *        1,398,800
Yosemite              CA 1864 *          760,917
Great Smoky Mountains NC/TN 1926 *       520,269
Wolf Trap Farm        VA 1966 *              130
;

proc print data=math;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the spaces after the * are also counted for the numbers, so if you have 9 spaces the number is empty, 8 spaces you get only first number, and so on...

**EDIT:**

Googled a bit and found a lot easier solution. Adding a & tells sas to ignore multiple blanks, so

```
value & COMMA9.;
```

should fix this problem the easiest way, at least it did in your testprogram.

**EDIT END**

Easiest solutions I can think of would be to remove all spaces except one after *, or add another delimiter (# for example) or increase the the size of value:

```
 Yellowstone           ID/MT/WY 1872 * 4,065,493
 Everglades            FL 1934 * 1,398,800
```

or

```
data math;
infile datalines delimiter='#'; 
 ...
Yellowstone#ID/MT/WY#1872#*#4,065,493
...
```

or

```
value COMMA20.;
```

Comment: I can't modify source file, so only last works for me. What about if I have another variable after these numbers?

Comment: @PNPTestovir: As far as i know, that should make no problem, because the first blank is always used as seperator, so everything between blanks will be recognized as variable. Another option would be to run a compress on your infile, this will remove multiple blanks and reduce them to one.

Comment: @PNPTestovir: Found another solution which worked with your test data, added it to my answer, maybe this works better for your case.